# How to copy or cast a Dataset into an Arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, dataset

In the code below, *Scanner* can not support **Dataset** type as its constructor. So, How can I convert or copy a Dataset into an **Arraylist** in java?

```
Dataset data = ARFFHandler.loadARFF(new File ("C:/KDDCUP1999/KDDCUP1999.arff"), 4);

Scanner s = new Scanner(data);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());
}
System.out.println(list);
s.close();
```

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Just FYI it is in Java Machine Learning library..I believe OP is using that

Comment: @0bijan mortazavi You can iterate using a for loop

Comment: dear @AniketSahrawat, the first line is correct. it's in *java.io.File* header. I have run this line separately and it was correct. and I used JML library.

Comment: dear @Akshay, can u explain how and answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert a **Dataset** type to an **ArrayList** using *Scanner*. if u want to read a Dataset type, u can use **JML** library or **Weka** package. it is very useful for data scientists. u can read your *datasetname.arff* Dataset in Weka and convert it to text file. then u can read this as a *datasetname.txt* file in your java program using *Scanner*.

Comment: Weka is a good tool for converting a dataset to any type of files.